# (Windows) sh.exe with OpenVPN (Windows)

Tags: openvpn

I've tried to install OPenVPN on a *Windows 2019 Server*. Everything has gone OK until i've tried to make the keys.

I'v analyzed and i get on the sh.exe file an error

If i run alone the .exe file, i get the same error.

**This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.**

Has someone got this issue?

What i've done
-Reinstall all Vc++ libraries

- install all .NET and ASP libraries from the server console
- Checked to run it as Administrator
- Reinstall all from the latest version